# How can I search for unique item on MongoDB with Prisma?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

I am trying to create a full-stack e-commerce website for learning purpose. I am using Next.js 13.4, MongoDB, Prisma.

I have request to take a single product, but I can't handle it's API route.

This is my Product model in Prisma schema;

```
model Product {
  id          String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name        String
  description String
  price       Float
  hasSale     Boolean?   @default(false)
  salePrice   Float?
  saleUntil   DateTime?
  image       String?
  stock       Int? @default(10)

  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt

  likes       Like[]    @relation("ProductLikes")
  cart        Cart[]    @relation("ProductCart")

  category    Category  @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId  String @db.ObjectId
}
```

And this is the route file

```
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const productId = request.url.split("/")[3];
  let products;
  try {
    if (productId !== null) {
      products = await prisma.product.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: productId,
        },
        include: {
          category: true,
        },
      });
    } else {
      products = await prisma.product.findMany({
        include: {
          category: true,
        },
      });
    }
    console.log(request.url);
    return NextResponse.json(products);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, "FETCH PRODUCTS ERROR");

    return new NextResponse("Something went wrong", { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

This is the error;

```
Inconsistent column data: Malformed ObjectID: provided hex string representation must be exactly 12 bytes, instead got: "api", length 3.
```

Comment: What line is the error occuring on? Have you inspected the value of the `productId` variable that you are using as a filter in the `findUnique()` call? Presumably the url may contain `/api/` at some point which your hardcoded `.split("/")[3]` assignment is grabbing.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. The error on the 
where: {
   id: id
}

part. When I console log the productId, it's true and String.
I hardcoded the .split part because I had different error when I use Next useRouter or such...

Comment: What does "_it's true and String_" mean? What is the _value_ of it (for executions when the error happens)? I'm not saying to can't hardcoded the split, but double check that it's the fourth entry in the split `request.url` string that contains the value you are interested in, the error suggests it does not

Comment: You are right. It was the problem. I was too sure that I took the correct value after splitting. I checked the value of productId and it was wrong. Sorry. And thank you for your help.